# Teradata - Run query on each table, return to same result set

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to find the max value for a field from all tables, in a few databases.  I used Excel to write the queries for all 900+ tables.

```
SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl1' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl1;
SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl2' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl2;
SELECT 'db2' Db,'tbl1' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db2.tbl1;
```

The problem is this returns 900+ Answersets.  I would like 1 Answerset, that I can copy into Excel for analysis.
I know that I could change the SQL to insert the data into a table, then export from that table.  Yet, I'm assuming there is a way to write a For-Each(type) loop.  Something like:

```
Foreach tablename in tablenamess (SELECT DATABASENAME, TABLENAME, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT)
From DBC.TABLESV
WHERE DATABASENAME IN ('Db1', 'Db2')
```

Is anything like this possible in Teradata?

Comment: Why don't you ÙNION ALL those Selects? `SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl1' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl2' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl2 UNION ALL
SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

No. And even if you could, that would still generate 900 result sets.

Use the "insert individual results to a table, then select from that table" approach or do the looping in Excel (using VBA) and insert each of the results into a new row in your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl1' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db1' Db,'tbl2' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db1.tbl2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db2' Db,'tbl1' Tbl, MAX(LOAD_DT) AS MAX_LOAD_DT FROM db2.tbl1;
```

This returns one result set, but you still need to explicitly list each database and table.  You can use metadata tables and SQL or a spreadsheet to generate the code, if you like.